# How to append a TextRange to flow document without losing formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, textrange

I need to add the `TextRange` to flow document without losing formatting done to it in `RichTextBox`. I am getting `RichTextBox.Text` which converts it to string and lose all the formatting but I don't want to loose formatting of text read from `RichTextBox`.

```
TextRange t = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
String s = t.Text;

FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
  /*
    this snippet works but looses formatting
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.Inlines.Add(s);
    fd.Blocks.Add(p);
  */
fd.Blocks.Add(t); // cannot convert TextRange to Block
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit the question to show what you've tried. Like this we will be able to better understand your problem/question and thus we will be able to better help you. It is best to provide a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: RichTextbox has Document property (guessing it should be with formatting) - Try adding it to Section.

Comment: document property is working but it divides the content in to columns

Answer (score 0):

RichTextBox.Rtf will give you the original content with formatting.  So, something like this, perhaps?

```
FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument();
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(flowDoc.ContentStart, flowDoc.ContentEnd);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtb.Rtf)))
{
    textRange.Load(ms, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```